# VsCode's syntax highlighting incorrect colors syntax for Java Development

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Overview of incorrect syntax highlighting
[image]

Lines 24, 25 show incorrect syntax highlighting which is effected by how many new empty lines I have in-between the last declared variable, and
System out println function.

In the image above, there is one empty space between line 22 and 24. If I have three empty lines the syntax highlighting returns to normal.

Showing that syntax highlighting corrects it's self with three spaces between code lines

[image: Showing that syntax highlighting corrects it's self with three spaces between code lines]

See below three images where syntax highlighting remains inconsistent while writing out         System out println

Image of System

[image: Image of System]

Image of System out

[image: Image of System out]

Image of system out println incorrectly highlighted

[image: Image of system out println incorrectly highlighted]

I have tried uninstalling any packages that help with syntax highlighting in VsCode, and reinstalling them, however problem persists.

I am hoping the syntax highlighting remains consistent

Comment: This seems like a bug. You should report it to the Visual Code project.

Comment: One line method `IntStream.of(7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).mapToObj(val -> DayOfWeek.of(val).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH) + "s Temperature:").forEachOrdered(sb -> System.out.printf("%-23s %d%n", sb, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100)));`

Comment: first report it at the Java extension Repo, what do the TextMate Scopes tell you of the different colored pieces

Comment: I have fixed the issue by renaming the Main.java file to WeatherApp.java and I am unsure why the issue existed when the file was named Main.java. I had also allowed something to refactor the code, but I will also report to Visual Code Project.

Comment: 1) if you raise an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it. 2) please edit this question post to add the code in a code block so we can copy and paste to reproduce the issue. 3) potentially related on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16szhue/how_can_i_fix_the_issue_with_color_coding_on_line/

Comment: Can you paste your code? Please see 

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)